# EXCEL 2013: Auto sorting in worksheet_change not firing

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am attempting to automatically sort data based on two columns when the data in the selected range changes.

This data is calculated from data entered on a separate sheet.  As it stands now, the data has to be manually sorted by highlighting the dataset and going to the DATA/SORT menu each time it changes.  My research seemed to show that entering a Worksheet_Change Sub in the sheet that the dataset is displayed should work.

The range of the dataset in question is A3:J11 with A3:J3 representing column headers.  I want it to sort first on column C descending and then Column I descending.  There is data displayed beneath this dataset that I do not want to be affected by the sort.

I have tried an extensive variety of methods to get this to work.  I am entering the sub by right-clicking the applicable sheet name and selecting View Code.

For some reason it is not firing.  Below is the latest code I have tried.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        Range("A3:J11").Sort _
            Key1:=Range("C4"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
            Key2:=Range("I4"), Order2:=xlDescending, _
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot....

Comment: Could you confirm whether it works when you manually run the macro? [go to View Ribbon -> Macros -> Execute]. You will need to change it to Sub Worksheet_Change... instead of Private Sub Wo.... in order to access it in this way. It is possible that the macro runs but does nothing because the code is wrong. [Because you give it the Target as Range, you will need to fiddle with it and just declare the testing variable yourself within the sub].

Comment: My guess is that when you are pasting the data, the "target" is the bottommost right cell affected by the paste, which might be further to the right than the "ByVal" Target provided when the worksheet changes. Consider instead holding a public Range variable which shows all variables in column C. Then any time the worksheet is changed, see if column C is different from the stored variable. If it is, perform your sort, and set the new Public Range variable to be equal to the new column C.

Comment: Here is where I stand now.  I have added a Module (SortPage) which consists of one sub..... pasted below...        Sub Sorter()
       
        Range("B4:K11").Sort _
        Key1:=Range("D4"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        Key2:=Range("J4"), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
   
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question to include your revised attempt, and walk through your code line by line, to check each variable value, and confirm that it operates as you expect. When it stops operating as you expect, tell us how you know that. ie: is there an error (what error), or is a variable a different value than you expected. Even just at the outset - when you run it, what is the value of Target - is it what you expected?

Comment: The SortPage.Sorter routine works perfectly when I run it as a macro.  I have the following in the Worksheet_Change which is not working.Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   

    Run SortPage.Sorter
    
     
End Sub

Comment: sorry....I am new at this...

Comment: I assume the Target value is not what you anticipated it to be. Check to confirm that the Target value, when you run it through the "worksheet change" option, is equal to "D4" (which is what you appear to want). To do this, you can click within your VBA code module to the left of the text, in the grey wall. This creates a "STOP", and when the code gets to that point it will break, and allow you to go into the code module and run through it line by line by pressing F8.

Comment: thank you for your patience and your responses